# How to extract a field from a Splunk search result and do stats on the value of that field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have following search results

```
2021-07-14 17:12:55,525 INFO [NiFi logging handler] returned 202: response_time:0.029 retry_count:2
```

Out of this I would like to extract "response_time" values like this so I can find the average, max, min, etc.

```
response_time:0.029
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use `rex` for that.  It uses regular expressions to extract matching text into fields.  For example,

```
... | rex "response_time:(?<response_time>\S+)"
| stats min(response_time) as Min, max(response_time) as Max, avg(response_time) as Avg
```

Comment: Can you not just use the named field from the field extract if you do that already?

Comment: Yes.  If the field is already extracted then you do not need to use `rex`.

Comment: how would you convert a duration into something similar to this to make dashboard? like if my value is "Runtime : 0:05:48.731730" Here 0 minutes and 5 seconds is what I am interested.

Comment: That's a question deserving of its own posting.  I'd use `rex` to break the duration into its component parts then use `eval` with the concatenation operator to put them into the desired format.